# Removing multiple series of characters from a string

Tags: javascript

Is there a fast and simple way to remove more than one series of characters from a string when knowing the index of each?

Here's an example.

```
Hello you lovely world!
```

I would like to remove both `you` and `world!`

Comment: whats the input and whats the output...

Comment: Index of what? How do you define "series of characters"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider writing your own method for splitting multiple indexes

check the following code snippet

```js
var str = "Hello you lovely world!"
var arr = str.split(" ")
multiSplice([1, 3])

function multiSplice(indexes) {

  indexes.sort(function callback(a, b) {
    return a - b
  })
  for (let i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
    const index = indexes[i] - i
    arr.splice(index, 1)
  }
}
console.log(arr.join(" "))
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var str = 'Hello you lovely world!'; str.replace(/(you).*(world)/,'lovely')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = $('div').text().replace(/you/g, '');
$('div').text(str);

var str = $('div').text().replace(/world/g, '');
$('div').text(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">hello you lovely world!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` to remove the words

```js
var _sstring = 'Hello you lovely world!'
var newstr = _sstring.replace('you', '').replace('world', '')
console.log(newstr)
```

You can also use regex to replace in one turn

```js
var _sstring = 'Hello you lovely world!'
var newstr = _sstring.replace(/you|world|/gi, '')
console.log(newstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert to array and splice items out of it

```js
var str = "Hello your lovely world";
var array = str.split(" ");
array.splice(1,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will produce the string "Hello lovely", as follows:

```
var str = "Hello you lovely world!";
var arr = str.split(" ");
arr.splice(1, 1);
arr.pop();
str = arr.join(" "); 
console.log(str);
```

See [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwjpMK)

The code splices "you" from the array. Then, the array's pop() method rids  itself of "world".

Alternatively you may use the replace method of str with a regular expression, as follows:

```
var str = 'Hello you lovely world!';
var re = /you|world!|[" "]/g;
var str2 = str.replace(re,"").replace("lovely"," lovely");
console.log(str2);
```

See [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vmaoKN)

A  partial string matching "you" or "world!" or a blank space gets converted into an empty string by providing  str.replace() with a regular expression as its first parameter instead of simply a string as in the second use of replace which effectively inserts a space in str2.